# angular checking object values before inserting key

Tags: angular, typescript

How do we insert new key value if partnerTermStart and partnerTermEnd are not null from the res.items objects?

if partnerTermStart and partnerTermEnd are not null then insert new key partnerCam where value if based on the computeTermYears result .

insert partnerCam only if partnerTermStart  and partnerTermEnd not null

Is there a cleaner way we can check each object partnerTermStart and partnerTermEnd are not null and then insert new key insert new key partnerCam. Thanks.

#my current code

```
 const newArr = res.items.map(v => ({...v, partnerCam: this.computeTermYears(new Date(v.partnerTermStart) , v.partnerTermEnd)}))
```

#function to insert computatedDate

```
computeTermYears(startDate: Date, endDate: Date){
    let computedYears = null;
    if(startDate && endDate){
      const totalDays = AppUtils.Days360(startDate, endDate);
      computedYears =  totalDays / 360;
    }
    return this.partnerTerm = computedYears.toFixed(2);
  }
```

#sample object

```
[
    {
        "id": 248,
        "name": "248-A",
        "dealType": "Idle Buyout",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": 349006.08,
        "firmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "cashContribution": null,
        "cashFlow": 125535.65376980315,
        "description": null,
        "wagAnnualCurrent": 349006.08,
        "wagFirmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "partnerTermStart": "2021-10-28T00:00:00"
        "partnerTermEnd": "2021-10-28T00:00:00"
        "partnerCam": null,
  
    },
    {
        "id": 249,
        "name": "249-B",
        "dealType": "PM Restructure",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": 349006.08,
        "firmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "cashContribution": null,
        "cashFlow": 125535.65376980315,
        "description": null,
        "wagAnnualCurrent": 349006.08,
        "wagFirmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "partnerTermStart": null,
        "partnerTermEnd": null,
    },
    {
        "id": 258,
        "name": "251-D (copy)",
        "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": 349006.08,
        "firmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "cashContribution": null,
        "cashFlow": 125535.65376980315,
        "description": null,
        "wagAnnualCurrent": 349006.08,
        "wagFirmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "partnerTermStart": "2021-10-28T00:00:00",
        "partnerTermEnd": "2021-10-16T00:00:00",
        "partnerCam": 2323,
   
    },
 
]
```

Comment: simply make the arrow function in the .map to a normal function and add the key only after checking for both the keys' values. Does this have anything to do with angular?

Comment: Do you need copies of your objects, or why are you using `map()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you don't need copies of your objects, I would prefer something like this:

```
items.forEach(v => {
  if (v.partnerTermStart && v.partnerTermEnd) {
    v.partnerCam = this.computeTermYears(new Date(v.partnerTermStart), v.partnerTermEnd);
  }
});
```

**Working example**

```js
const items = [
    {
        "id": 248,
        "name": "248-A",
        "dealType": "Idle Buyout",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": 349006.08,
        "firmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "cashContribution": null,
        "cashFlow": 125535.65376980315,
        "description": null,
        "wagAnnualCurrent": 349006.08,
        "wagFirmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "partnerTermStart": "2021-10-28T00:00:00",
        "partnerTermEnd": "2021-10-28T00:00:00",
        "partnerCam": null,
  
    },
    {
        "id": 249,
        "name": "249-B",
        "dealType": "PM Restructure",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": 349006.08,
        "firmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "cashContribution": null,
        "cashFlow": 125535.65376980315,
        "description": null,
        "wagAnnualCurrent": 349006.08,
        "wagFirmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "partnerTermStart": null,
        "partnerTermEnd": null,
    },
    {
        "id": 258,
        "name": "251-D (copy)",
        "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": 349006.08,
        "firmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "cashContribution": null,
        "cashFlow": 125535.65376980315,
        "description": null,
        "wagAnnualCurrent": 349006.08,
        "wagFirmTermRemainingCurrent": 17.666666,
        "partnerTermStart": "2021-10-28T00:00:00",
        "partnerTermEnd": "2021-10-16T00:00:00",
        "partnerCam": 2323,
   
    }, 
];

function computeTermYears(startDate, endDate) {
  let computedYears = null;
  if (startDate && endDate){
    const totalDays = 42;
    computedYears =  totalDays / 360;
  }
  return this.partnerTerm = computedYears.toFixed(2);
}

items.forEach(v => {
  if (v.partnerTermStart && v.partnerTermEnd) {
    v.partnerCam = this.computeTermYears(new Date(v.partnerTermStart), v.partnerTermEnd);
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(items, null, 2));
```

Comment: what if I wanted to add and modify new key for example 
v.wagAnnualCurrent = AppUtils.numberWithCommas(v.wagAnnualCurrent); , how do I assign it only if for example wagAnnualCurrent  has value

Answer (score 1):

You can have a simple Typescript function.

```
for( for item of res.items){
   if(item.partnerTermStart != null && item.partnerTermEnd != null) {

      // Do you stuff like adding to Array or anything else.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your map add check for start and end, also in `computeTermYears` function instead of null declare `computedYears` as `let computedYears = 0;`.

```
const newArr = res.items.map(v => {
  if(v.partnerTermStart && v.partnerTermEnd){
    return {...v, partnerCam: this.computeTermYears(new Date(v.partnerTermStart) , new Date(v.partnerTermEnd))};
  }
  return v; 
);
```